# Are EXTENDED VARCHAR2 baned to become synchronized record fields?

Tags: oracle, sqldatatypes, appian

My app is built on an Oracle Database.

Would it be possible to overcome the 4000 byte of Text limitation we have for Synchronized Record fields of [appian](/questions/tagged/appian)?

I know the `VARCHAR2(4000)` limitation is considered to be a standard column type by Oracle, then choosing the `EXTENDED` for param. `max_string_size` in the DB would make it an "extended data type", as `CLOB` is. But since `CLOB` is forbidden to become a Snyc. RT field, would my large `VARCHAR2` columns be also forbidden?

Asking for people who tried it. If no one did, I will ask the DBA, but could be easier to ask here ;)

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is, don't bother with the extended string option. It provides no real benefit. A varchar2 greater than 4KB is a CLOB under a different name.

Comment: yes, but my goal is to cheat Appian :)